# Text getting split into new lines due to <br> tag while scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a page and the data in it but not able to get the expected data in one line due to br tags present in text because of which the data is getting moved to new line any help would be appreciated.

Following is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import random
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\chromedriver.exe")
with open(r"E:\office\Zoro\Zoro11.txt" ,'r')as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    currentIndex = 0
    with open(r"E:\office\Zoro\Zoro16.csv", 'a')as f1:
        f1.write("Product Url" + "," + "Main category"+"," + "Sub category"+"," + "Leaf category"+","+"Title" + "," + "Prodcutid"+","+"Manufacturer Name" + "," + "Manufacturer's number"+","+"reviews"+","+"Price"+","+"smalldesc"+","+"Product Dimensions"+","+"Main Image"+","+"Sub Image")
        f1.write("\n")
        for link in content[currentIndex:]:
            driver.get(link)
            time.sleep(5)
            aj = driver.find_element_by_class_name('zcl-breadcrumb__list').text.replace("Home\n","").replace("\n",">").replace(",","")
            try:
                title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-za='product-name']").text.replace(",","").replace("\n","")
            except:
                title = "No title"
            try:
                brand = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-za='product-brand-name']").text.replace(",","")
            except:
                brand = "No Brand"
            try:
                productid = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-za='PDPZoroNo']").text.replace(",", "")
            except:
                productid = "No productid"

            maincategory = aj[:aj.find(">")]
            Leafcategory = aj[aj.rindex('>')+1:]
            Subcategory = aj[(aj.find(">"))+1:aj.rindex('>')]
            mfrnu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-za='PDPMfrNo']").text.replace(",", "")
            try:
                mainimage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/main/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/img').get_attribute('src')
            except:
                mainimage = "No mainimage"
            try:
                price = driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-price__price').text
            except:
                price = "No price"
            try:
                smalldesc = driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-attributes').text.replace("\n",";").replace(",","")
            except:
                smalldesc = "No desc"
            try:
                specification = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-specifications__table.table.table-striped').text.replace("\n",";").replace(",","").strip()
                print(specification)

            except:
                specification = "No sepcs"
            try:
                productdesc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-description__text').text.replace(",","")
                
            except:
                productdesc = "No productfields"
            f1.write(link + "," + maincategory + "," + Subcategory + ","+ Leafcategory + ","+title + "," + productid + "," + brand + "," + mfrnu + "," + price +"," + smalldesc +"," + specification +"," + productdesc +"," + mainimage +"\n")
```

in the above code in the productdesc i am getting the following output

```
Pro Series Swivel Head LED Work Light
  280 lumens
Beam Distance 54 meters
Run time 3 hrs
```

the expected output is all in one line with space
the link that i am using to scrape is https://www.zoro.com/dorcy-pro-s-swivel-head-led-worklght-187-lumen-41-2392/i/G9576141/

Comment: Please provide sample data from Zoro11.txt so I can test. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike67 the sample data from zoro11.txt is https://www.zoro.com/dorcy-pro-s-swivel-head-led-worklght-187-lumen-41-2392/i/G9576141/

Comment: @Mike67 the sample data from zoro11.txt is https://www.zoro.com/dorcy-pro-s-swivel-head-led-worklght-187-lumen-41-2392/i/G9576141/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to update the line for reading description. Add the newline replace like you did in the other fields:

Change this:

```
productdesc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-description__text').text.replace(",","")
```

To this:

```
productdesc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.product-description__text').text.replace("\n",";").replace(",","")
```